# Cómo descargar una imagen .webp desde una url en c#

Tags: c#, url, descarga

Quisiera saber cómo descargar una imagen .webp desde una url.
Tengo una aplicación en la que se descargan imágenes de internet a partir de url´s, pero cuando la extensión es .webp se genera la excepción: **System.ArgumentException: El parámetro no es válido.**
Cada proceso de descarga se gestiona en un objeto de la clase:

```
internal class DatosUrl
{
    public string url = "";
    public Image imagen = null;
    public string error = "";
    public TimeSpan tiempo;
}
```

La descarga se realiza con:

```
try
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2");
    client.Headers.Add("Content-type", "application/json");
    byte[] byteImage = client.DownloadData(datosUrl.url);
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(byteImage);
    datosUrl.imagen = Image.FromStream(memoryStream);
    client.Dispose();
    memoryStream.Dispose();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} Excepcción capturada.", e);
    datosUrl.error = e.Message;
}
```

He intentado hacer la descarga de otras dos maneras. Esta una:

```
HttpWebRequest peticion = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(datosUrl.url);
HttpWebResponse respuesta = (HttpWebResponse)peticion.GetResponse();
datosUrl.imagen = Image.FromStream(respuesta.GetResponseStream());
```

y esta otra:

```
WebClient client1 = new WebClient();
client1.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2");
client1.Headers.Add("Content-type", "application/json");
Stream stream = client1.OpenRead(datosUrl.url);
datosUrl.imagen = Image.FromStream(stream);
client1.Dispose();
stream.Dispose();
```

De las tres maneras se produce la misma excepción:
**System.ArgumentException: El parámetro no es válido.**
He probado pasar como url distintas direcciones locales:

C:\Users\usuario\Documents\Nueva carpeta\nombre.webp

C:\Users\usuario\Documents\Nueva carpeta\nombre.jpg

Y el resultado es el mismo, el proceso es correcto en el .jpg y excepción con el .webp

Bueno pues mi pregunta es, ¿Cómo descargar una imagen .webp desde una url?. Gracias.

Comment: ¿Por qué añades la cabecera `application/json` si devuelve una imagen?

Comment: Lo pongo conjuntamente con el user-agent, porque ley en un hilo que de esta manera puedes descargar imagenes de servidores que retornan un error de acceso prohibido, el (403), peor no se si  esto es así correcto.